# django on shared hosting (greengeeks)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get django setup on my greengeeks shared hosting account.

I (mostly) followed the instructions [here](http://www.codekoala.com/posts/installing-django-shared-hosting-site5/), and in addition have installed flup to my local python 'site-packages' directory.

My python is 2.4.3, and I created a 'local' copy of it in `~/bin` and `~/lib/python2.4`.

I'm using django 1.3 (latest release that still supports python 2.4.x).

**Edit**:
ok, so last time it was about getting python working (and calling django)....

SO, I've got django working - if I run:

python /home/icebreak/www/cgi-bin/mysite.fcgi

then the django output gets printed to stdout.  Great!

HOWEVER, when I navigate to [www.icebreakersent.com](http://www.icebreakersent.com), whatever is printed to stdout from django doesn't appear!  Only the output that is printed in the mysite.fcgi file makes it to the browser.

To get around this issue, I edited the flup cgi server file to SAVE the data being sent to the stdout as a file.  Then, I load this file in the mysite.fcgi script and print it to the screen.  **This WORKS**.  *However*, it's a workaround for an issue I don't understand.

So, my question to you guys is - why is data that is being printed to stdout from within flup/django NOT showing in the browser?  And why is it showing just fine in the console?

My cgi file is called 'mysite.fcgi' and is located in my `~/public_html/cgi-bin` directory.
It's contents are:

```
#!/home/icebreak/bin/python
import sys, os
import traceback

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/icebreak/bin/python")
sys.path.append("/home/icebreak/lib/python2.4/site-packages")
sys.path.append("/home/icebreak/bin")
sys.path.append("/home/icebreak/django_projects/icebreak")

# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
os.chdir("/home/icebreak/django_projects/icebreak/mysite")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "mysite.settings"

#from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
#def test_app(environ, start_response):
#    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
#    yield 'Hello, world!\n'

#WSGIServer(test_app).run()

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print 'BEGIN'
try:
    runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false", outlog="/home/icebreak/django_out.log", errlog="/home/icebreak/django_err.log")
    #runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
except Exception, e:
    #print '<br>'
    #print 'oops, error occured in runfastcgi...'
    #print '<br>'
    #print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    #print '<br>'
    #traceback.print_exc()
    #print "Couldn't do it: %s" % e
    pass

f = open('/home/icebreak/django_projects/icebreak/mysite/okiedokie.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
f.close()


#from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
#application = WSGIHandler()


#from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
#from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
#WSGIServer(WSGIHandler()).run()

print '<br>'
print 'END'
```

My .htaccess file is in `~/public_html` and has the contents:

```
# Use PHP5CGI as default
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler application/cgi .fcgi
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
AddHandler cgi-script .fcgi
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options ALL

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# PHP based site (www.jarrettchisholm.com) - currently not working (July 18, 2012)
RewriteRule ^(jarrettchisholm.com/.*)$ jarrettchisholm.com/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

# Django based site (www.icebreakersent.com)
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(static/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(cgi-bin/mysite.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cgi-bin/mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this working properly??

Comment: 1. Your rewriterule seems to be commented out. 2. What does the Apache log say?

Comment: hey @DanielRoseman, thanks for commenting..
I commented out the rewriterule because it didn't seem to make a different (after install flub, it looks like it's handling redirecting to my cgi file).  I can't seem to find the apache log files anywhere on my shared hosting server (via ssh access).

Comment: I'm not sure how flup can be doing the redirecting. Flup is a basic FCGI server, but something still has to tell Apache that when you request `www.mywebsitename.com/mysite` it should be serving it via `/cgi-bin/mysite.cgi/`. You'll need to ask your hosting company where you can access the Apache logs.

Comment: hmm..I asked my host, and they gave me the logs for the morning (normally i don't have access).  Here's what they say:
`[Sun Jul 15 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client 184.151.61.68] Premature end of script headers: mysite.cgi, referer: http://www.icebreakersent.com/
[Sun Jul 15 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client 184.151.61.68] File does not exist: /home/icebreak/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://www.icebreakersent.com/
  File "/home/icebreak/public_html/cgi-bin/mysite.cgi", line 13, in ?`
i guess there's a problem with my cgi file...

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated question with further information...thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: calling mysite.cgi (also made some changes to mysite.cgi) using 'python mysite.cgi' from my ssh I get the full html dumped to the console!  And it looks fine!  Howerver, from the front end it still gives 500 error.  If I actually do 'print blah' in the mysite.cgi before the runfastcgi(..) call it outputs on the front end (but stuff from django doesn't show)....is django not printing to standard out or something..?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: ok...looks like an issue with the runfastcgi function...after putting a try/catch around it, I get the following error:
`Unexpected error: socket.error
Couldn't do it: (22, 'Invalid argument')`
any ideas anyone? :)

Comment: @TankorSmash Sort of - I can't recall exactly what I did, but I got it working for a while, but it wasn't stable (if I recall correctly, it would sometimes stop working, then work again).  In the end, I left GreenGeeks and bought a VPS through Namecheap.  Good luck :)

Comment: I have setup a nice wsgi server at GreenGeeks in 2022.  Django and Flask still seem to be a reach for the setup.  The cpanal has a nice Python App deployment menu, with terminal. Coding a pure wsgi site takes serious work.